# Get windows 7 desktop to act like linux

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the multiple desktop utility you suggest for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1498/what-is-the-multiple-desktop-utility-you-suggest-for-windows)

There is a guy at my job that has a Unix OS, something like Ubuntu or something like that. Anyways he has the capability to slide his desktop. It makes it a great use if you dont have multiple monitors. I was wondering windows 7 had a app like that. Cause I dont like one windows 7 already have. you know, the one that has windows that pop up and you can toggle. I would whether slide my desktop

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The app is called "Wubi".

I hope that isn't too flippant of an answer. Consider it "tongue-in-cheek", people, not "flippant", ok?

Comment: This could have been a valid answer if you had taken the time to actually explain what it does and/or why it solves the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Well, sliding desktops isn't part of the standard linux install either. For windows [infinite screen](http://ynea.futureware.at/cgi-bin/index.pl) might work - i've been meaning to try it out but have had other things to take care of.